# How to use awk for filtering(perl automation)

Tags: linux, perl, awk

This is my txt file

```
type=0
vcpu_count=10
maste=0
h=0
p=0
memory=23.59
num=2
```

I want to get the vcpu_count and memory values and store it in some array through perl(automating script) .

```
awk -F'=' '/vcpu_count/{printf "\n",$1}' .vmConfig.txt
```

i am using this command just to test on terminal.but am getting a blank line. How do i do it. I need to get these two values and check for condition

Comment: Perl or awk? Which one is it?

Comment: Since you use printf, you want a format specifier(just like in C). printf "%s\n", $1 (or $2) will do

Comment: Given the subject line `How to use awk for filtering(perl automation)` you're a;most certainly going to get the answer to your question instead of being shown the right way to solve your problem. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/361691.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Perl anyway, just use Perl for this too.

```
my %array;
open ($config, "<", ".vmConfig.txt") or die "$0: Could not open .vmConfig.txt: $!\n";
while (<$config>) {
    next unless /^\s*(vcpu_count|memory)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*\n/;
    $array{$1} = $2;
}
close($config);
```

If you don't want the result to be an associative array (aka hash), refactoring should be relatively easy.

Comment: I'd probably just slurp the whole lot into a hash in one go:

`my %config_hash = do { local $/; <$config>} =~ m/(\w+)=([\d\.]+)/gm` - and then `print $config_hash{$_} for qw ( vcpu_count memory )` or similar. (Left as a comment, because it's not materially different from your answer)

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

***Solution 1st:***

```
awk '/vcpu_count/{print;next} /memory/{print}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
vcpu_count=10
memory=23.59
```

***Solution 2nd:***
In case you want to print the values on a single line using `printf` then following may help you on same:

```
awk '/vcpu_count/{val=$0;next}  /memory/{printf("%s AND %s\n",val,$0)}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
vcpu_count=10 AND memory=23.59
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use `awk -F'=' '/vcpu_count/{printf "\n",$1}' .vmConfig.txt` there are a couple of mistakes. Firstly, `printf "\n"` will only ever print a new line, as you have found. You need to add a format specifier - something like `printf "%s\n", $2` will treat field 2 as a string and add it into the printed string. Checking out `man printf` at the command line will explain a bit more,.

Secondly, as I changed there, when you used `$1` you were using the first field, which is the key in this case (while `$0` is the whole line.)

Triplees solution is probably the most appropriate, but if there is a particular reason to start awk to perform this before perl, the following may help.

As you have done, it splits on `=`, but then outputs as `csv`, which you can change as appropriate. Even if input lines are not always in same order, will output in predictable order on single line

```
awk 'BEGIN {
        FS="=";
        OFS=","  # tabs, etc if wanted, delete for spaces.
    }
    /vcpu_count/  {cpu=$2} 
    /memory/      {mem=$2} 
    END           { print cpu, mem }'
```

This gives

```
10,23.59
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining so thoroughly